# Wanting text to overflow into another div

Tags: html, css

Beginner CSS question here.

I have the home page of a website I'm working on set out perfectly. I have two `divs

```css
#desktop-navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 height: inherit;
 padding: 0 45px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav ul {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 35px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 25px;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Thasadith;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#desktop-navbar #mobile-menu-link{
 display: none;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li:hover {
 font-weight: 900;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper.solid {
   transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#desktop-logo.solid-fonts {
   transition: color 1s ease 0s;
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 100%,  #000 0%) fixed;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper nav li.solid-fonts {
  transition: color 1s ease 0s;
  color: #000000;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18vw;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: black;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#home {
 height: 700px;
    position: relative;
}

#home-container {
 height: inherit;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 position: absolute;
}

#home-colour-one {
 height: inherit;
 width: 33%;
 background-color: #314455;
}

#home-colour-two {
 height: inherit;
 width: 67%;
 background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="desktop-navbar">
  <div id="desktop-nav-wrapper">
      <nav>
          <ul id = "desktop-nav-content">
              <li class="desktop-items"><a href="#home">Casa</a></li>
              <li class="desktop-items"><a href="#about">Sobre Mi</a></li>
              <li class="desktop-items"><a href="#services">Servicio</a></li>
              <li class="desktop-items"><a href="#gallery">Galería</a></li>
              <li class="desktop-items"><a href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
              <li id="mobile-menu-link"><a>Menu</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
 </div>

<div id="home">  
    <div id="home-container">
    <div id="home-colour-one">
     <h3>Bettoo Kaozink</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="home-colour-two" class="container">
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

side by side with different colours (I know I could use one `div` and use the CSS gradient method, but I want to add some sweet fade-in to both of these `divs` at a later point).

But I want to place the text on the halfway point between the two `divs` (so one half is in the blue and the other half is in the grey).

Right now, I only have the text in one `div` of the home page (`home-colour-one`), but I'd like it to be spread across the two. Is there a way I can get the text to overflow into the grey `div` (`home-colour-two`)? Or just have the text in a separate div and place on the point separating the two `divs`?

I also know I can have the `H3` of Bettoo Kaozink in the nav bar, but that is something I want to avoid. As ideally, I would like Bettoo Kaozink centered vertically in the container.

Cheers

Comment: Please don't use `heading` elements to style your page - for accessibility and ease of reading down your page for screen readers, your `h3` should be a `h1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is by using flexbox by adding `display: flex` to the container. If you haven't learned about how flexbox works, I'd recommend you to read up on [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I've created a mini prototype [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GamerMatt/jq5x86sn/51/) of what you wanted. There are two things you should do to the JSFiddle in advanced to help you understand the code a bit better:

1. On line 15 of the CSS code, change the `flex-grow` property to some other value.
2. Use JavaScript to center the text relative to the `div-container`

Once you understand flexbox, it opens a door to so many different options that you can choose from.

I hope that it works out for you. If not, just tell me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the structure of your page, based on what I can understand from here, it's not so solid.

Anyway, just in this context, and if I get right your goal, so having your h3 (or whatever text container you will add then) floating between the two divs [id="home-colour-one" and  id="home-colour-two"], and centered vertically, a solution would be adding this ad the end of your CSS:

```
/* ADD THIS!!!*/
#home-colour-one h3 {
position: absolute;
top:50%; left:16.5%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here a JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/ralicul/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks man. But out of curiosity, why don't you think it's solid?

Comment: Just some incongruences especially in your CSS (for instance I don't think you got how to use flex-box yet) and maybe also in the direction you seem to take with your design ideas. But the context here is limited so, take it as a feeling.

Comment: For your first few projects, you shouldn't really worry about incongruences. Just get things to work. As time goes on, you'd have learned how to clean up your code and create more efficient solutions for any problem.